# PHP not starting after nginx in entrypoint

Tags: php, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am trying to get PHP-fpm to run after nginx runs, but when i try to do so with my code, nginx runs fine but php does not start within docker and i will have to manually start it.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
service php7.4-fpm start
```

This is run after `ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/var/www/html/entrypoint.sh"]`

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`nginx -g 'daemon off;'` will make nginx to stay in the foreground, so that Docker can track the process properly. As it never exits, your `service php7.4-fpm start` never have chance to run.

As a fix, you may could swap the 2 lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
service php7.4-fpm start
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: When i do that, the console just gets stuck and nothing outputs when i run the image

Comment: Your run it without add `-d`? It's as expected, all container should have a foreground process as PID1, the PID1 exit, the container exit. So if you don't use `-d` when start the container, it will never exits.